# Laravel / Livewire: How to ignore image validation while updating a model without changing the image

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Livewire component to perform basic CRUD operations on a `Bottle` model including the upload of an image. *create()* and *update()* methods use the same form via a pop-up modal.

Uploading the image works fine. However, if I update the dataset **without** changing the image, the validation always fails stating that the uploaded file must be an image.

I figured out that the validation is using the image path stored in the DB (as assigned in the *edit()* method) instead of an actual uploaded image. Hence, validation fails. If I change image by uploading a new one, everything works fine.

Any ideas how to ignore the image validation in case the image has not changed? Thank you!

**Bottle.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

use App\Models\Bottle;

class Bottles extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $bottle_id;
    public $modalVisible = false;

    public $name;
    public $type;
    public $photo;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.bottles', [
            'bottles' => Bottle::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $this->resetInputFields();
        $this->showModal();
    }

    public function showModal()
    {
        $this->modalVisible = true;

        $this->resetErrorBag();
        $this->resetValidation();
    }

    public function closeModal()
    {
        $this->modalVisible = false;
        $this->resetInputFields();
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $bottle = Bottle::findOrFail($id);
        $this->bottle_id = $id;
        
        $this->name = $bottle->name;
        $this->type = $bottle->type;
        $this->photo = $bottle->photo;

        $this->showModal();
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'type' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'photo' => 'nullable|sometimes|image|max:5000',
        ]);

        if ($this->photo != "") {
            $photoPath = $this->photo->store('photos', 'public');
        }
        else {
            $photoPath = null;
        }

        $data = array(
            'name' => $this->name,
            'type' => $this->type,
            'photo' => $photoPath,
        );

        $bottle = Bottle::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->bottle_id], $data);

        $this->closeModal();
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        Bottle::find($id)->delete();
    }

    private function resetInputFields(){
        $this->name = '';
        $this->type = '';
        $this->photo = '';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this as the following :-

use sometimes only you dont need nullable because sometimes validation rule validate the photo if the request contain image .

```
 public function store()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'type' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'photo' => 'sometimes|image|max:5000',
        ]);

        $data = array(
            'name' => $this->name,
            'type' => $this->type,
        );
        if (request()->hasFile('photo')){
            $data['photo'] = $this->photo->store('photos', 'public');
        }
        $bottle = Bottle::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->bottle_id], $data);

        $this->closeModal();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, that doesn't work as I am using a Livewire component. I think it doesn't work via ```$request```variable ...

Comment: try , replace this 
        if ($request->hasFile('photo')){
            $data['photo'] = $this->photo->store('photos', 'public');
        } 

with this :-

        if (is_file($this->photo)){ // or !empty($this->photo) will work
            $data['photo'] = $this->photo->store('photos', 'public');
        } 

or this 
        if (request()->hasFile('photo')){ // or Input::hasFile() will work
            $data['photo'] = $this->photo->store('photos', 'public');
        }

Comment: I think the problem is that the error is already thrown within the ```validate()``` method. Your suggestion is fine to handle the storing of the file. But the validation will stay fail.

Comment: What was the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario when trying to update the profile avatar of an user. I ended up using a custom validator and combining parts of the [livewire docs (see custom validations section)](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation) and the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#complex-conditional-validation)

As the livewire docs says you should create a custom validator like this:

```
$validatedData = Validator::make(
        // first parameter contains the fiels to be validated
        ['email' => $this->email],
        // second parameter contains the rules
        ['email' => 'required|email'],
        // third parameter contains custom messages
        ['required' => 'The :attribute field is required'],
    )->validate();
```

But in order to implement the conditional validation you shouldn't call the `validate()` method yet.

```
$validatedData = Validator::make(
        ['email' => $this->email],
        ['email' => 'required|email'],
        ['required' => 'The :attribute field is required'],
    );
```

So the custom validator object holds partial rules and then you call the `sometimes()` method passing the field, rules and a closure that must return true for the rules to be added (laravel docs).

```
$validatedData->sometimes('avatar', ['required', 'image'], function(){
   return some_true_or_false_condition
});
```

Finally to validate the data you should call the `validate()` method.

```
$validateData->validate();
```